# Regex for a string combination

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

```
NSString *fmtpAudio = @"a=fmtp:111 ";
NSString *stereoString = @";stereo=1;sprop-stereo=1";
NSArray *componentArray = [localSdpMutableStr componentsSeparatedByString:fmtpAudio];
if (componentArray.count >= 2) {
    NSString *component = [componentArray objectAtIndex: 1];
    NSArray *fmtpArray = [component componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
    if (fmtpArray.count > 1) {
        NSString *fmtp = [fmtpArray firstObject];
        NSString *fmtpAudioOld = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fmtpAudio, fmtp];
        fmtpAudio = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", fmtpAudio, fmtp, stereoString];
        NSString *stereoEnabledSDP = [NSString stringWithString: localSdpMutableStr];
        stereoEnabledSDP = [stereoEnabledSDP stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: fmtpAudioOld withString: fmtpAudio];
        localSdpMutableStr.string = stereoEnabledSDP;
    }
}
```

Consider below example String:

```
a=fmtp:93 av=2\r\n
a=fmtp:111 av=1\r\n
a=fmtp:92 av=2\r\n
```

1. In the above example string, `a=fmtp:111` can appear anywhere in the string.
2. We have to get the string between `a=fmtp:111` and the next first appearance of `\r\n` which is `av=1` in our case
3. Now we have to append `;stereo=1;sprop-stereo=1` to  `av=1` and append back to the original string.
4. The final output should be

   a=fmtp:93 av=2\r\n
   a=fmtp:111 av=1;stereo=1;sprop-stereo=1\r\n
   a=fmtp:92 av=2\r\n

Is it possible to achieve the above chunk of logic with Replace with Regex pattern?

Comment: Could you please explain in plain English what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Added as you have suggested. can you please check now.

Comment: Are `\r\n` just CRLF endings (i.e. two chars)? Or literal text (i.e. four chars)? Is that *example string* really an `NSString`?

Comment: Yes. they are CRLF endings @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```objectivec
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *fmtpAudio = @"^a=fmtp:111 .*";
NSString *stereoString = @"$0;stereo=1;sprop-stereo=1";
NSString *myText = @"a=fmtp:93 av=2\r\na=fmtp:111 av=1\r\na=fmtp:92 av=2";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:fmtpAudio options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:myText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myText length]) withTemplate: stereoString];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

Output:

```cs
a=fmtp:93 av=2
a=fmtp:111 av=1;stereo=1;sprop-stereo=1
a=fmtp:92 av=2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NXEyBA/1).

*Details*

- `^` - start of a line (`^` starts matching line start positions due to the `options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines` option)
- `a=fmtp:111`  - a literal string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

The `$0` in the replacement pattern is the backreference to the whole match value.

Comment: Working like a charm. Upvoting and accepting as the answer.